# List directory stack in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to list the directories that have been added to the directory stack using the command:
`pushd`

I cannot find any references or command on how to print the directory stack contents.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: do you need to keep the stack or won't you mind if it gets lost?

Comment: The only thing I could think of is to `popd` the stack, store the (restored) current directories in some array-like variables and to re-`pushd` them then. If you only need to know the stack size, check out the [`prompt $+`](http://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html)...

Comment: With a `$+` in the prompt you can see the depth of the stack, but otherwise I don*t know a way to obtain stack entries aside from popd/ %CD%

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `pushd` without parameters outputs the list of the stacked directories.

```
pushd c:\
pushd windows
pushd help
pushd windows
pushd en-us

pushd
```

Will output

> c:\Windows\Help\Windows
>   c:\Windows\Help
>   c:\Windows
>   c:\
>   c:\Temp

The latest pushed directory is missing here, but can simply retrieved by `%__CD__%`.

And there is one more directory (in my case `C:\temp`), as that will be the directory after the last executed `popd`.

Comment: I never noticed that behavior before. Strange, considering that I use that command regularly. You clearly won this code-golfing `:D`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Interesting, this also works on linux but with a little bit of a difference. On linux in addition to printing the stack, we are moved to the directory at the top of the stack.

Comment: @Phuthib, to achieve the same in Windows `cmd`, simply do `popd` afterwards to achieve the same as in Linux; if the stack should not be touched, to `pushd "%CD%"` afterwards to repush...

Comment: I wonder why this does not work in powershell.

Answer (score 5):

Nice challenge. <strike>As already noted, there seems to be no built-in way to get that information, so you need</strike> a script to do it step-by-step:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set origin=%cd%

rem build a demo stack:
pushd c:\
pushd windows
pushd help
pushd windows
pushd en-us

rem get stack step by step:
set i=0
:loop
  popd && (
    set /a i+=1
    echo !i! --- %cd%
    set "p[!i!]=%cd%"
   ) || (
    goto :TopOfStack
   ) 
goto :loop

:TopOfStack
echo stack empty.
cd %origin%
rem restore stack:
set p[
for /l %%i in (%i%,-1,1) do (
  pushd "!p[%%i]!"
)
```

Note: see also [jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50463544/2152082)'s answer.

Comment: When you put the `goto :loop` inside the `&&()` the `||()` part isn't neccessary

Comment: Thanks LotPings, I do find your answer helpful, and will keep it for future reference. But will award @Jeb as the correct answer as I was more looking for a single command.

Comment: @LotPings: true, but I wanted to show the "else part" too. Phuthib: please don't rename me, I like my name `:D`. And yes, jeb's answer is to be preferred (unless you really need the variables)

Comment: It looks like `pushd` output can't be processed by a `for /f` nor piped (just redirected to a file). So your batch has an advantage.