# How to print the directory stack in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to print the recently visited directory stack to save it to a file for later retrieval. According to [this](https://ss64.com/ps/get-location.html) powershell documentation for [Get-Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-location?view=powershell-7), it should be possible with:

```bsh
Get-Location -Stack
```

But that only seem to work if you have previously done a `Push-Location`, which I can't be bothered with. Because I know Powershell 7+ keep track of your stack without this. So I want to access the internal directory stack and print it out without having to use additional commands to save location every time I do a `cd`.

**How can I print the full internal directory stack using Powershell?**

---

Related answers:

- [List directory stack in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462331/list-directory-stack-in-windows) (using CMD)

---

UPDATE: 2020-10-13

Some of the code for the internal stack seem to be in [SessionState.cs](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/16f0b74187d7ab6da0f73ba207bc3a9a2a86f1b9/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/SessionState.cs#L54-L106). There you will also notice the way too small stack size: `locationHistoryLimit = 20;`. It would be great to be able to change this, as a starter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rm alias:cd
set-alias cd push-location
cd ..
cd ~
pwd -stack

Path
----
C:\Users
C:\Users\me
```

Comment: This is actually a pretty good answer. However, (1) I have already aliased `cd` to do something else, and (2) it doesn't address how Windows is accessing the directory stack internally, and how we can use that. Let's wait and see if someone can come up with something else.

Comment: @not Why do you assume that any internally available information were to have a public interface?

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, it's indeed an assumption of having used Windows for a lifetime, and where I can no longer recall anything not being accessible in some way or another. I suppose it depends on your own definition of *public interface*. Is writing registry items and or using Powershell with inline C# to intercept/modify windows handles not *public*?

Comment: What is a more relevant question then, should be why the *public* `push-location` stack is not already populated (or synchronized) by/with the internal one?

Comment: @not The definition of a public interface is fairly simple to understand: It comes with documentation and contractual guarantees. You appear to be confusing this with an implementation detail that happens to be observable.